# Programmatically call one action from run script action in install4j

Tags: java, install4j

How to call the **"Copy files and directories"** action from a **"Run Script"** action in install4j?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
import com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.CopyFileAction;

CopyFileAction action = new CopyFileAction();
action.setFiles(new File[] {new File("origin.txt")});
action.setDestinationFile(new File("target_file_or_directory"));
action.execute(context);
```

Other properties are discoverable in code completion.